# Excel VBA Version number from Sequential number

Tags: vba, excel

All,

I have an Excel spreadsheet which gathers files from various locations which have version numbers at the end of their name.

eg

Filea_v1.1.xlsm
Filea_v1.1.1.xlsm
Filea_v9.1.xlsm
Filea_v11.1.1.xlsm

I have already stripped the details of the file and left with the version number, but I'm finding it hard to code to get the latest version. When using a simple

```
  If LatestVersion > LatestVersion_Last
  ' 11.1.1 > 9.1
```

I get a FALSE output as it thinks the 9.1 is greater than 11.1.1 (as its held in a string). I can't convert to a number that I'm aware of as it contains more than one decimal place.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Fucntion CompareVersion( strVersion1 as String, strVersion2 as String)

strVersion1 = "Filea_v11.1.1.xlsm"
strVersion2 = "Filea_v9.1.xlsm"

strVersion1 = Replace(strVersion1, "Filea_v", "") 'remove prefix
strVersion1 = Replace(strVersion1, ".xlsm", "") ' remove suffix
strVersion1 = Replace(strVersion1, ".", "") 'remove dots

strVersion2 = Replace(strVersion1, "Filea_v", "") 'remove prefix
strVersion2 = Replace(strVersion1, ".xlsm", "") ' remove suffix
strVersion2 = Replace(strVersion1, ".", "") 'remove dots

Dim strVersionArray1 as String()
Dim strVersionArray2 as String()

strVersionArray1 = Split(strVersion1,".")
strVersionArray2 = Split(strVersion2,".")

Dim i as Integer
For i=LBound(strVersionArray1) To UBound(strVersionArray2)
    If (Cint(strVersionArray1(i))>Cint(strVersionArray2(i))) Then
          'strVerion1 is greater than strVersion2
          GoTo EXIT_FUNC:
    Else If (Cint(strVersionArray1(i))<Cint(strVersionArray2(i))) Then
          'strVerion is greater than strVersion2
          GoTo EXIT_FUNC:
    Else If (Cint(strVersionArray1(i))=Cint(strVersionArray2(i))) Then
          'we need to examine the next segment of the array
    End if
Next i
```

EXIT_FUNC:
    End Function

Comment: Thanks for that, but if I had 8.1.1 there, this would then be higher than 9.1 (811 and 91)

Comment: and the solution to that is to pad "9.1" to the length of "8.1.1" so that "9.1" becomes "910" and is greater than "8.1.1" (which after processing becomes "811")

Comment: Thanks @FunkSoulBrother. I still have an issue with it though as Padding does fix some parts, but not all. If I had 11.1 and 9.1, it would pad 9.1 out to 910 and be greater than 111.

Comment: It looks like you'll need two comparisons - one for the whole number (convert the number to an integer) and if they are equal - then compare the decimal. I'll edit the code so you can review it.

Comment: I took another approach - split the version number into a string array and compare each segment of the array. maybe it needs some tweaking but I think it's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try something like this:

```
Function FctLatest(ByVal LatestVersion As String, ByVal LatestVersion_Last As String) As Boolean

Dim comparedNew, comparedOld As String

'Loop to remove the versions one by one
Do
    'For the new version
    comparedNew = CutString(comparedNew, LatestVersion)

    'For the previous version
    comparedOld = CutString(comparedOld, LatestVersion_Last)

    'we eliminate the case of equal versions
    If CInt(comparedNew) > CInt(comparedOld) Then
        FctLatest = True
        GoTo endFunction
    ElseIf CInt(comparedNew) < CInt(comparedOld) Then
        FctLatest = False
        GoTo endFunction
    End If

Loop While InStr(LatestVersion_Last, ".") <> 0 Or InStr(LatestVersion, ".") <> 0

'For the new version
comparedNew = CutString(comparedNew, LatestVersion)

'For the previous version
comparedOld = CutString(comparedOld, LatestVersion_Last)

'we eliminate the case of equal versions, and choose the first one input
If CInt(comparedNew) > CInt(comparedOld) Then
    FctLatest = True
ElseIf CInt(comparedNew) < CInt(comparedOld) Then
    FctLatest = False
End If

endFunction:

End Function


Private Function CutString(ByVal ReturnedString, ByRef InputString As String) As String

'For latest version
If InStr(InputString, ".") = 0 Then
    ReturnedString = InputString
Else
    ReturnedString = Left(InputString, InStr(InputString, ".") - 1) 'Adding the first part of the version
    InputString = Right(InputString, Len(InputString) - InStr(InputString, ".")) 'Removing the first part of the version
End If

CutString = ReturnedString

End Function
```

It returns a boolean comparing the versions you're interested in.

Regards,

Pierre.

Edit: just added cases, as it wasn't functional in the first place.

Comment: Hi Pierre, Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it doesn't do what I'm after. It brings back 1.8 not being higher than 1.7

Comment: Yes, I just edited the code to fit that case.
Could you try it again?

Answer (score 0):

This function returns 1 if the version of the first input string is bigger, -1 if the second one is bigger and 0 if both are equal:

```
Function Compare(a As String, b As String) As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim aarr() As String
    Dim barr() As String
    Dim av As Integer
    Dim bv As Integer

    aarr = Split(a, ".")
    barr = Split(b, ".")

    n = LBound(aarr)
    Do
        av = -1
        If UBound(aarr) > i - 1 Then av = CInt(aarr(i))
        bv = -1
        If UBound(barr) > i - 1 Then bv = CInt(barr(i))

        If av = -1 And bv = -1 Then
            Compare = 0
            Exit Function
        End If

        If av > bv Then
            Compare = 1
            Exit Function
        End If

        If av < bv Then
            Compare = -1
            Exit Function
        End If

        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Function
```